# Adding another column to select output SQL

Tags: sql

I wrote this

```
SELECT BrojRacuna 
FROM Racun LEFT OUTER JOIN Stavka 
ON IDRacun=RacunID, 
SELECT UkupnaCijena 
AS 'Ukupna cijena' FROM Stavka;
```

BrojRacuna means bill number, Racun means bill and UkupnaCijena means price total. Basically I want to add column which outputs price total and is called Ukupna cijena in the same query as the first SELECT LEFT OUTER JOIN. What is the way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT table.column, table.another_column, another_table.column FROM joins`

Comment: What's your DBMS? What's the criteria for computing the total_price ?

Answer (score 1):

Some guessing:

```
SELECT BrojRacuna, UkupnaCijena AS Ukupna_cijena 
FROM Racun 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Stavka 
    ON IDRacun=RacunID
```

You should add aliases to your tables and qualify the columns with that:

```
SELECT r.BrojRacuna, s.UkupnaCijena AS Ukupna_cijena 
FROM Racun AS r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Stavka as s 
    ON r.IDRacun=s.RacunID
```

It makes it a whole lot easier to understand the query for the next person

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
select 
  Racun.BrojRacuna,
  Stavka.UkupnaCijena AS 'Ukupna cijena'

FROM Racun inner join Stavka 
ON racun.RacunID= stavka.RacunID
```

in order to do the join right you need to join a a certain and similar column to both tables. like I did on RacounID (I dont know if both your tables have that column)

Comment: how would that look like with my example just edited?

Comment: Which example? I cannot see the example you 'just edited', and that was > 30 minutes ago... 

Comment: was that answer helpful MARKO?